# Android IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android, rest

I am new to Android. What I am trying to do is to get a String via a web service when I press a button and write the String in a text field.

Manifext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AndroidClientActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="myClickHandler"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="hello">Hello World, AndroidClientActivity!</string>
<string name="app_name">AndroidClient</string>
<string name="button">Message</string>
<string name="myClickHandler">myClickHandler</string>
```

AndroidClientActivity.class:

```
package com.maze.client;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class AndroidClientActivity extends Activity {

private EditText text;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
}

public void myClickHandler(View view){
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:

        WebResource wbr;
        Client client = Client.create();
        wbr = client.resource("http://my.ip.address:8080/MazeService/rest/service/hello");  
        String result = wbr.queryParam("number", "10").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
            text.setText(result);
        break;
    }

}
```

}

This doesn't work. I get this error in the LogCat(please help me edit it right):

```
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  ... 11 more
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660): Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:503)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.maze.client.AndroidClientActivity.myClickHandler(AndroidClientActivity.java:32)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  ... 14 more
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:77)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:479)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:240)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
02-08 23:39:04.423: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  ... 19 more
02-08 23:39:08.343: I/Process(660): Sending signal. PID: 660 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Help us to help you... format your logcat.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Buried in the stack trace is `Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` on Android 3.x and up, you can't do network I/O on the main thread (which is what you're trying to do). You'll want to do the network request with an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Thank you, that was it.. for the moment. Yet, I face another problem: [please help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204134/android-restful-client)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was going crazy.
Only you have to add this code in the **FIRST LINE** of the `onCreate` method of the activity that throw your Error! (before of `super.onCreate`):

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: For a quick workaround this may sound good, but to keep your app off the Dark Side you should do resource intensive tasks (such as network operations) in separate threads.